# Information passing between extra_actions

Tags: bazel, bazel-extra-action

I have an `action_listener`:

```
action_listener(
    name = "foo_listen",
    mnemonics = [
        "Foo", # Foo might usually take several minutes
    ],
    extra_actions = [
        "foo_action_pre", # Start some processing
        "foo_action_post", # Finish parts of processing that needs action output
    ],
)
```

In `foo_action_pre`, I set

```
out_templates=[
    "foo_action_pre_data",
],
```

in order to pass information to `foo_action_post`.

Now when I add `$(location foo_action_pre_data)` to the `cmd` of `foo_action_post` Bazel complains, that it is not a prereq.

No matter whether I add that to `tools` or `data` though, it never is detected as a prereq. How can I declare the correct dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$(output foo_action_pre_data)` instead of `$(location foo_action_pre_data)`.

See [extra_action.cmd](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/extra-actions.html#extra_action.cmd).